# How to find value in row of table using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to find value in row of table. Sample , i have a this case

```js
    $("tr[id*='row']").each(function (i, el) {
            //if($this.value() >10)
            //console.log('This value in cell is: ' + this.value);
        });
```

```html
<div id='div1'>
    <table border='2px'>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border='2px'>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row' style="background-color:yellow; color:red">
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border='2px'>
        <tr id='row' style="background-color:yellow; color:red">
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border='2px'>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row' style="background-color:yellow; color:red">
            <td>15</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In this case above , i want to compare and show the value in cell, which more than 10, but i confused in define the value in cell. Mabe you can give me adviced for this case .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find`  for `td` values.

```js
$("tr[id*='row']").find('td').each(function(i, el) {
var val = $(this).text();
if (val > 10)
  console.log('This value in cell is: ' + $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1'>
    <table border='2px'>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border='2px'>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row' style="background-color:yellow; color:red">
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border='2px'>
        <tr id='row' style="background-color:yellow; color:red">
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border='2px'>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row' style="background-color:yellow; color:red">
            <td>15</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear sir, you forget compare with ```10``` , if more than , show ```this.value```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr[id*='row']").each(function () {
  var td = $(this).find("td");
  var countdeeptd = td.length;
  td.each(function(i,el){
   if(td.eq(i).text() > 10)
    console.log('This value in cell is: ', td.eq(i).text());
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1'>
    <table border='2px'>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border='2px'>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row' style="background-color:yellow; color:red">
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border='2px'>
        <tr id='row' style="background-color:yellow; color:red">
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border='2px'>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row' style="background-color:yellow; color:red">
            <td>15</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```